# execCommand not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am unable to get `document.execCommand('SaveAs', false, "/home/prakash/temp/log.html")` to work in either Firefox or Google Chrome, any ideas ? Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: We won't know if you're doing something wrong, unless you're showing us some code :) Have you set `contentEditable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

[You may find this resource useful :)](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=27&t=885605)

---

**Quoting:**

> Available only in the Win32 platforms
>   for IE, the execCommand( ) method
>   executes the named command.

Source: http://javascript.gakaa.com/document-execcommand-4-0-5-.aspx

**More Specific Resource:**

- [execCommand compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html)

Comment: Oh damn ! 
Is there anyway, I can write to a file from javascript in firefox ?

Comment: Great that should work fine for me :)
Just have a java applet that can perform the same.

Comment: Current versions of all the major browsers have implementations of `document.execCommand()`, so the page you linked to is out of date.